Kivy: RecycleView does not show when implemented in Python but works when written in KV language
I am new to Kivy. Learning by building a simple app.
I want to show a list of items at the top (Used RecycleView widget for this). At the bottom will be a text box (used TextInput widget) and button (used Button widget) to enter new items. The code for the app is given below.
When the app is run, the textbox and button show up, but the recycle view does not show up.
If I use builder.load (string given below) instead of the class definitions for BulletListLayout (which is exactly the same as the parameters in init of RecycleBoxLayout), it works. I am intentionally trying to make it work in pure python so that I understand how the KV language maps to python objects.
Builder.load_string('''
<BulletList>:
    viewclass: 'Button'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')


Please help me in understanding why it does not work when everything is python.
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from journal.backend.daily.logic import GetAllBulletsLogic, AddBulletLogic
from kivy import metrics


class NewBullet(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hint_text = "Enter your new bullet here"
        self.focus = True

class BulletListLayout(RecycleBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print('in bullet list layout')
        self.default_size= (None, metrics.dp(56))
        self.default_size_hint= (1, None)
        self.size_hint_y= None
        self.height= self.minimum_height
        self.orientation= 'vertical'


class BulletList(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.viewclass = 'Button'
        layout = BulletListLayout()
        self.layout_manager = layout
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
        self.add_widget(layout)

class NewBulletEntryView(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.height=metrics.dp(40)
        self.size_hint_y=None
        self.new_bullet = NewBullet(size_hint_x=0.9)
        self.button = Button(text="Add", size_hint_x=0.1)
        self.add_widget(self.new_bullet)
        self.add_widget(self.button)

class DailyLogApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        bullet_list = BulletList(data=[{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)] )
        new_bullet_entry = NewBulletEntryView()
        layout.add_widget(bullet_list)
        layout.add_widget(new_bullet_entry)
        return layout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DailyLogApp().run()


In your build() method of BulletListLayout, you set the height to self.minimum_height:
self.height= self.minimum_height

This sets the height of the BulletListLayout to its minimum_height at the instant when this code is evaluated. Since the BulletListLayout has no children at that point, the minimum_height is 0, so this code sets the height to 0, and that height is never updated.
One of the things that the kv code does is to create bindings. So when you have in kv:
height: self.minimum_height

Kivy creates a binding using the above information to modify the height whenever the minimum_height changes. This only works for Properties.
The equivalent python code (that can be placed in the __init__() method of the BulletListLayout) is:
self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))

Another minor detail is that you set the viewclass of the BulletList before you set the layout_manager. Perhaps a bug in the RecycleView, but you must set the layout_manager before setting the viewclass, otherwise the viewclass does not get passed to the layout_manager.
So, I think that the following class definitions will get your code working:
class BulletList(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = BulletListLayout()
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(100)]
        self.add_widget(layout)
        self.layout_manager = layout
        self.viewclass = 'Button'


class BulletListLayout(RecycleBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.default_size= (None, metrics.dp(56))
        self.default_size_hint= (1, None)
        self.size_hint_y= None
        # self.height= self.minimum_height
        self.orientation= 'vertical'
        self.bind(minimum_height=self.setter('height'))


This worked well. Thanks a ton for pointing this out. Your explanation helps me understand how Kivy works as well.
